# in VBA (word) how do I add a comment to a range only if no comments exist?

Tags: vba

Using a range.Find object in a Word document I loop through all matches and add a comment.

But if a comment already exists I do not want to add another comment - so I can run VBA script numerous times on same document.

Here is my loop:

```
Dim all As Range
Set all = pcSetupFind(word, wdFindStop)  ' setup all.find to find 'word'
While all.Find.Execute
  If all.Find.Found Then
    If all.Comments.Count = 0 Then Call all.Comments.Add(all, comment)
  End If
Wend
```

But, it always adds a comment.

How do I add a comment on a range only when no comment exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to check if a comment is already attached to a given part of the document (a word, a sentence -- a **Range**), then you have to compare that range to the ranges of any/all existing comments.

```
Option Explicit

Function CommentExistsInRange(checkRange As Range) As Boolean
    '--- compares all existing comments to the given range and
    '    checks for a match.
    '    RETURNS true if a comment exists for the given range
    Dim commentScope As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim totalComments As Integer
    totalComments = ActiveDocument.Comments.Count
    CommentExistsInRange = False
    If totalComments > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To totalComments
            Set commentScope = ActiveDocument.Comments.Item(i).Scope
            If (checkRange.Start = commentScope.Start) And _
               (checkRange.End = commentScope.End) Then
                CommentExistsInRange = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End Function

Sub FindAndComment(findText As String, searchRange As Range, newComment As String)
    Dim foundTextRange As Range
    With searchRange
        .Find.Text = findText
        .Find.Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Find.Forward = True
        While .Find.Execute
            If .Find.Found Then
                .Select
                Set foundTextRange = ActiveDocument.Range(Selection.Range.Start, _
                                                          Selection.Range.End)
                If Not CommentExistsInRange(foundTextRange) Then
                    Call ActiveDocument.Comments.Add(foundTextRange, newComment)
                End If
            End If
        Wend
    End With
End Sub

Sub Test()
    FindAndComment "Office", ActiveDocument.Range, "Around the Office watercooler"
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your effort. However I what a count of comments on a particular range (usually a single word). Counting comments on whole document will not solve my problem - unless ActiveDocument does not do what I think it does - it refers to whole document doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, ActiveDocument does refer to the whole doc. I misunderstood your original question. In order to determine if your found text has an attached comment, you have to compare the range of the found text to the list of comments in the document. I've updated the code snippet above to show this.

Answer (score 0):

I took PeterT's method and implemented it differently.

```
Function pcHasComments(rng As Range) As Boolean

  Dim com As comment

  For Each com In ActiveDocument.comments
    If com.scope.Start = rng.Start And com.scope.End = rng.End Then
      'MsgBox ("found comment")
      pcHasComments = True
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next

  pcHasComments = False

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @philcolbourn, much more efficient and simple!

Comment: @PeterT: You are welcome. Although I needed your idea. I guess if I wanted comments within this range then I would need a more complex conditional.