# Adding Content Controls and Retrieving User Selections

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I have Word 2013 documents containing anywhere from 7 to over 100 sections of text. For simplicity's sake, I'll call them bios. 
**Goal**: provide a drop-down box for each, with 3 options, then and tally the selections after they are chosen.
I am very new to VBA and only learning by what I can google. What I have so far is:

```
Sub AddStateDropDown()
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim sum As Integer
Dim maxnumber As Integer
sum = 0
Counter = 1
maxnumber = 31
```

My "playground" document has 31 bios.

```
For Counter = 1 To maxnumber Step 1

sum = Counter + sum
Selection.Range.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlDropdownList)
Selection.ParentContentControl.Title = "Bio " & sum
Selection.ParentContentControl.Tag = "Approval" & sum
Selection.ParentContentControl.DropdownListEntries.Clear
Selection.ParentContentControl.DropdownListEntries.Add Text:="Approve", _
    Value:="Approve"
Selection.ParentContentControl.DropdownListEntries.Add Text:="Hold", Value _
    :="Hold"
Selection.ParentContentControl.DropdownListEntries.Add Text:="Delete", _
    Value:="Delete"
Next Counter
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, this results in the error "*Run-time error '4605': This method or property is not available because the current selection partially covers a plain text content control.*"
To the best of my knowledge, this is a concern about the available space for the content control, but I receive this error no matter the free space above, below, or beside my cursor when starting the macro.

I am trying to number the tags or titles in this manner for the final tally - As I understand it, I will need to use SelectContentControlsByTag or SelectContentControlsByTitle to recover the values selected. Could anyone help me overcome the hurdles of

**1)** Adding multiple differentiated content controls, preferably after each instance of a particular word or phrase (something to spread them across the bios)

**2)** Retrieving information from those content controls

Thanks in advance! StackOverflow has been very helpful for my fledgling VBA experiments, but this time I'm forced to write my own question.

Comment: This is a big project. I don't know how to offer help without becoming engaged. Therefore I need to subscribe to your solution before I offer help. Please describe the appearance of the result. Will every bio in the document have a dropdown? Will the result, with selected comments shown, be printed? Will the values to be summed up be shown (for example, Approve = 3, Hold = 1, Delete = 0)? How and where will the total be shown?

Comment: Consider the following alternatives. (A) Use Word "Comments" instead of content controls. You might semi-automate them somehow. (B) Use a single content control to appear next to the current selection, write the result to a separate "report doc", and colour the selection to show that it's done. (C) Create a userform in which you can call up bios, one at a time, with Next and Back buttons if you like, and write the comment either to the document (as text or comment) or to a "report doc".

Comment: Every bio will have a dropdown, but nothing will need to be printed. The values behind the labels will not need to be displayed; the primary purpose of this is to create table/Excel that shows the selection for each bio and tallies a count of each selection. Currently the practice is to manually add a comment to the unique identifier of each bio, then manually tally those comments in a separate Excel. I'm not opposed to using comments so long as the end goal can be achieved, but I'm not sure how that could be made to work.

Comment: Your (B) option sounds interesting, but I'm not sure how "single content control next to current selection" will differ from single content control per bio. Is this a dropdown that would appear and disappear over the course of a macro being run? Regarding (C), I'm not familiar with userforms, but I'm interested in any solution that can create the table output I need.

Comment: Our discussion is likely to be boring for other forum users. Therefore I have created a chatroom where we can discuss it. I haven't done this before and don't know how or if it will work. Please bear with me. The chatroom I created is called "Bio Review". My response is there. Please find it and post your reply there. Leave a message here to alert me and I shall do the same. Meanwhile, if any of the more experienced users can help us in this endeavour please do so :-)

Comment: I can't find the d... chat room myself. There must be a way to link it to this thread. Perhaps someone will help. Meanwhile, the answer I posted there is repeated below.

Comment: So you have data for review in a Word document and you want the result of the review in Excel. Please give an example of one line of report as you want it to appear in Excel.


Please give some idea of the size of data in one "bio", perhaps a range of the number of characters or lines of text. Also, you describe each bio as a "section". Is that a Section as understood by Word? Is each bio a paragraph as defined by word? Or could there be several paragraphs to make up one bio?

Comment: Please describe the method of review as you imagine it to be most efficient. For example, will the reviewer be required to read all bios in a document, or may he be selective? Will the reviewer be likely to want to go back to change his mind on bios he already graded?


Obviously, the easiest method would be to look at each bio in turn, once, grade it and click the button to generate the Excel report. Please examine this scenario for practical faults. State the reasons why it couldn't work this way so as to find a design which meets all your criteria.

Comment: Sorry Variatus, I was unable to find the chatroom as well. 
The export can be in Excel or Word, so long as it's a table. I would prefer Excel eventually, but expect using a table in Word would make this slightly less difficult.
I can see the table being handled one of two ways.

1) Two columns, 1st being unique identifier or sequence number for each bio, 2nd being Titled "Status" with the selected option being listed next to each bio (Approve, Hold, Delete)

2) 4 columns, 1st being unique identifier or sequence # for each bio, 2nd-4th being Approve, Hold, or Delete, with "1"s beneath

Comment: Method of Review: What we're aiming for is the ability to create Word documents listing dozens of these bios, 1 per page, that are reviewed in their entirety. There will never be an instance where we pick and choose random bios; we will always start at the top and work our way down. It is forseeable that a decision can be changed as we progress further down the document, however. Ideally each bio gets rated (either by button, dropdown, whatever method) as it is reviewed, and a separate function allows one to generate a report of those ratings in table form.

Comment: Description of bios: Each has a sequence number and unique identifier on their second line (the first line provides titles overhead for these), followed by a classification, then the body of the text, and finally notes. The length of the body can vary greatly (e.g. 50 words vs. 200+), but all bios are less than 1 page (roughly 30-40 lines).

Answer (score 0):

The week is almost gone. It's time to make some headway. Please copy the following code into a standard module in a copy of your document with the test bios.

```
Option Explicit

Enum Ncb                        ' Context button
    ' 27 Jul 2017
    NcbCap
    NcbCmd
    NcbEvaluate = 0
    NcbApprove
    NcbReject
    NcbHold
    NcbReport
    NcbA = 80
    NcbH = 87
    NcbR = 97
    NcbRep = 720
End Enum

Private Sub DelContextControl()
    ' 06 Oct 2016

    ' ===================================================
    '      Use this sub to DELETE the context control
    ' ===================================================

    Dim Doc As Document
    Dim Ctl As CommandBarControl
    Dim Del As Boolean

    Set Doc = ActiveDocument
    CustomizationContext = Doc
    Do
        Set Ctl = CommandBars("Text").Controls(1)
        Del = (Ctl.Tag = BtnSpecs(NcbEvaluate, NcbCap))
        If Del Then Ctl.Delete
    Loop While Del
End Sub

Private Sub TestSet()

    ' ===================================================
    '      Use this sub to SET the context control
    ' ===================================================

    SetContextControl ActiveDocument
End Sub
Sub SetContextControl(Doc As Document)
    ' 27 Jul 2017

    Dim Cbar As CommandBar
    Dim Bctl As CommandBarControl
    Dim Fid As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    CustomizationContext = Doc
    Set Cbar = CommandBars("Text")

    Set Bctl = Cbar.Controls(1)
    If Not (Bctl.Tag = BtnSpecs(NcbEvaluate, NcbCap)) Then
        Set Bctl = Cbar.Controls.Add(msoControlPopup, , , 1)
        With Bctl
            .Caption = BtnSpecs(NcbEvaluate, NcbCap)
            .Tag = BtnSpecs(NcbEvaluate, NcbCap)
            .BeginGroup = True

            Fid = Array(NcbA, NcbR, NcbH, NcbRep)
            For i = NcbApprove To NcbReport
                With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
                    .Caption = BtnSpecs(i, NcbCap)
                    .FaceId = Fid(i - NcbApprove)
                    .OnAction = BtnSpecs(i, NcbCmd)
                End With
            Next i
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Private Function BtnSpecs(Bid As Ncb, _
                          Cid As Ncb) As String
    ' 27 Jul 2017

    Dim Specs As String

    Select Case Cid
        Case NcbCap
            Specs = "Evaluate Bios,Approve,Reject,Hold,Report"
        Case NcbCmd
            Specs = ",Approve,Reject,Hold,Report"
    End Select

    BtnSpecs = Split(Specs, ",")(Bid)
End Function

Sub Approve()
    ' 27 Jul 2017
    WriteComment NcbApprove
End Sub

Sub Hold()
    ' 27 Jul 2017
    WriteComment NcbHold
End Sub

Sub Reject()
    ' 27 Jul 2017
    WriteComment NcbReject
End Sub

Private Sub WriteComment(TxtId As Ncb)
    ' 27 Jul 2017
    ActiveDocument.Comments.Add Selection.Range, UCase(BtnSpecs(TxtId, NcbCap))
End Sub

Sub Report()
    ' 27 Jul 2017
    MsgBox "Create the report"
End Sub
```

Now run the procedure `TestSet` (F5). This procedure just calls the sub `SetContextControl`. It is "Test" because perhaps you will find a better way in the future. I don't like the use of `ActiveDocument` (may do much damage if run on the wrong document), and I don't like users to run around pressing F5.

This procedure will add a control to the context menu of the ActiveDocument's Content, meaning its body (excl. headers and footers). If, for any reason you want to remove the control, run the sub `DelContextControl`. Note that the control is available in the document where it is installed only, not the application. If you want it to remain in the document, you must save it.

The context menu is available on right-click while you are within its scope, meaning within the body of the document. When you right-click while operating somewhere else you will have a different context menu. The control the code is adding is the first one in the menu. It is called "Evaluate Bios". Note that everything about this control is negotiable. It is all in the code. All of it can be modified to your liking or requirements.

The control is of the popup type, meaning it opens a drop-down to its right. There you can select "Approve", "Reject", "Hold" or "Report". When you click any of the first three choices a comment will be added with the indicated content. When you click the fourth button you will be reminded of the next task.

Word attaches comments to a `Range`. The code uses the `Selection.Range` for this purpose. So, you might select the bio's title or the unique ID before inserting the comment. If you aren't careful of your selection you might attach the comment to the wrong bio. This is one area that might be improved.

Another area concerns the question of multiple comments. Since comments identify the commenter you might actually want to have multiple comments. If not, you can make sure that only one comment exists for each bio. This issue was dealt with at StackOverflow: [in VBA (word) how do I add a comment to a range only if no comments exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29425374/in-vba-word-how-do-i-add-a-comment-to-a-range-only-if-no-comments-exist)

Depending upon your workflow you may have to actually split your document into sections, one bio per section. I hope it will not be required, but if it is, it is something that might be done when preparing the document for commenting, perhaps at the same time as the context control is installed.

Similarly, the context control might be removed by the same code which creates the report. That involves creating a document (perhaps from a template, perhaps from scratch), looping through all the comments in the test document, counting their nature and writing the result to the new report document. It isn't difficult, but it's another day's work.

BTW, I do recall that you rejected the idea of using comments. If the ease of use doesn't convince you of this system please look for functions provided by Word to hide and show comments. But if even that doesn't convince you, the same macro that creates the comment could do something quite different, meaning the ease of use provided by the context menu could be maintained. There is no lack of possibilities, but to make the association between bio and evaluation visible to the commenter as immediate as the Word comment does would require a lot more programming than you see above.